# Getting localized month name

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm trying to get swedish month names from a date and no matter what I do it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried the following:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'sv_SE');
\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('sv_SE');
$monthstr1 = strftime('%B', strtotime('2019-02-12'));
$monthstr2 = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-02-12')->formatLocalized('%B');
```

Both the strings above return the string "February" although the swedish name should be "Februari" (and of course the same problem with other months). In my opinion both should return localized month names...

I'm using Laravel 5.7.25 with the included Carbon 1.36. I have the same problem on two servers (dev and test environments) both running Ubuntu 18.04 (PHP 7.2). I have checked /etc/locale.gen, everything is correct there.

Anyone spot what I could have missed?

Comment: Probably you don't have the Swedish localize package installed. You can check if you do and install if missing by following the steps in this article https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2015/07/php-date-setlocale-localisation/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Unfortunately it doesn't help though. Now language-pack-sv is installed but makes no difference. Also a date +"%B" from bash gives correct output, it's only in php it doesn't work.

Comment: I noticed there are some locales written like "es_ES.utf8" in Ubuntu, so change your setLocale (for carbon too) that way.